# How can I set Report Viewer language the same as CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, report, reportviewer

As I understood, by default, the language of report viewer is set by *"CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture"* (not that simple). That means, if my computer is from Brazil, then it will format numbers with Brazil's culture. Altought my data may be formatted with United States' culture, so my report viewer display things incorrectly. I guess one solution to solve it, is by changing the language of the report viewer as the same of my *CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture*.

How can I achieve that in the simplest way, please?

Answer (score 4):

In the report properties set the Language property as:

`=System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString()`

Or to whatever you need. I'm using a report parameter for example. **The value must resolve to a string**.

You can access the report properties via the properties window, and then from the top list select "Report". Or you could simply click in the gray area of the report, and press F4.

[image: Example].

Answer (score 0):

There are two (+1) separate things here:

1. The language of the controls, tooltips, etc. inside the ReportViewer control. This depends on the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.
2. The number, date, currency, etc. formats within the report. These are controlled by changing the `Language` property of the rdlc file in use.
3. The actual content of the report which is controlled via your DataSource(s). This one is pretty obvious, but I mentioned it for sake of completeness.